# Disable shortcut in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've recently updated my version of Visual Studio 2017 (from version 15.6 to 15.8), and an annoying thing happened:

I use an Italian keyboard, and on that keyboard to write the `}` symbol, you press the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> button combination. In VS 15.8 however, they seem to have introduced a new shortcut for that button combination, which seems to highlight the current code block that the cursor is in. This means that I cannot type the `}` character anymore... quite a problem when writing code!

How do I disable this shortcut?

Comment: I fear we're going to hear from every C# programmer in Italy.  Please edit the linked question so it is more likely that you would find it yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry, I clicked "the linked answer solved my problem" and I can't edit anymore. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I meant the original question, not this one.  I just don't know if "print" is a word that Italian programmers are likely to use when they talk about entering text into their text editor.